# Property transfer in SOAPUI using groovy script

Tags: groovy, properties, soapui

Hi i am new to soapui and have this situation.I have two service memberservice1 where the response has "Region" property.I need to check this property and see if its value is "SCR" i need to modify it to "SCA" and pass it to another WS memberservice2.

I tried this way but couldnt get it.Can anyone please suggest.

```
def smlholder = groovyUtils.getXMLholder("Webservice#request");
def node = smlholder.getnodevalue("//region");

if(node  == 'SCA')
    testRunner.testcase.testSteps("anotherwebservicename").setProperty('Region','SCR');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example code does not match you statement. Below I will follow your statement, and ignore the broken code example.

There are several different ways this cane be done. The easiest would probably be:

```
def region = context.expand("${Webservice#Response#//*:region}")
if (region == "SCR")
       testRunner.testCase.testSteps["anotherwebservicename"].setProperty("Region", "SCA");
else
       testRunner.testCase.testSteps["anotherwebservicename"].setProperty("Region", region);
```

Comment: Thanks SIKING.Should i also use the propertytransfer step after this to transfer the property ?

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to do. You certainly can.