# Transfer Property ids (Array) to other TestCases in SoapUI/Groovy

Tags: arrays, json, dictionary, groovy, soapui

I have an API to get list of ids, name, data etc. (TestCase name `GET-APIs_OrderdByID_ASC`)

I want to transfer those IDs to other following TestCases in same TestSuite or other TestSuite.

In SOAPUI, `Property Transfer` works within TestSteps in same TestCase. (Using OpenSource version). I need to transfer the property value among different TestCases / TestSuites.

[image: SOAPUI Preperty Transfer]

Below is the code that I can extract `ids` from one testCase and also name of testCases/testSteps where I want to transfer.

```
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.*
import com.eviware.soapui.support.types.StringToStringMap 
import groovy.json.*

def project = context.testCase.testSuite.project
def TestSuite = project.getTestSuiteByName("APIs")
def TestCase =  TestSuite.getTestCaseList() 
def TestStep = TestCase.testStepList
def request =  testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("List_of_APIs_OrderByID_ASC")
def response = request.getPropertyValue("Response")
def JsonSlurperResponse = new JsonSlurper().parseText(response)
def Steps = TestStep.drop(3)
log.info JsonSlurperResponse.data.id   
def id = JsonSlurperResponse.data.id

Steps.each {
    it.getAt(0).setPropertyValue("apiId", id.toString())   
    log.info it.getAt(0).name       
}
```

If I run above code, all the array values of id `[1, 2, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]` are set to each of the following testSteps

[image: Groovy Code property transfer]

I looked some other SO questions

- [Property transfer in SOAPUI using groovy script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31192398/property-transfer-in-soapui-using-groovy-script)
- [groovy-script-and-property-transfer-in-soapui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35497480/groovy-script-and-property-transfer-in-soapui)

Can anyone help me out. :-)

Comment: Every soapui testcases are independant. You can't pass some values like that. You can manage this case with a datasink in your testcase `GET-APIs_OrderdByID_ASC` or just write your properties to a file if you use the free version. Then in your second testcase, you call this properties file (datasource for pro version or read a file in groovy for the free one) and make a loop for each value.

Comment: @Lerminou Yes, I can write those ids in external file and take back ids from there to `setPropertyValue`. But I don't want to use any external file to store those value. It faces 2 problem - to give absolute path which is a hectic to use when I put it in server for regression and writing file and reading again are time consuming when it has a lot of data.

Comment: You can use relative path with `context.expand('${projectDir}')` which is your project directory.

Answer (score 0):

I have done something with datasinks as Leminou suggests.

Datasinks are a good solution for this.  In test A, create a datasink step to persist the values of interest.  Then in the target step, use a data source step, which links to the file generated by the datasink earlier.

The data sink can be configured to append after each test or start afresh.

If you're struggling to tease out the values for the datasink, create a groovy step that returns the single value you want, then in the datasink step, invoke the groovy.

Sounds a little convoluted, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use project level properties or testSuiteLevel properties or testCase Properties.

This way you can achieve the same thing that you get from Property Transfer step but in a different way.

Write a groovy step in the source test case to setProperty(save values you want to use later)

```
testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue("TCaseProp", "TestCase")
testRunner.testCase.testSuite.setPropertyValue("TSuiteProp","TestSuite")
```

testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.setPropertyValue("ProjectLevel","ProjectLevelProperty")

"TCaseProp" is the name of the property. you can give any name
"TestCase" is the value you want to store. You can extract this value and use a variable 
for example

```
def val="9000"
testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue("TCaseProp", val)
```

You can use that property in other case of same suite. If you want to use across different suites you can define project level property

use the below syntax in target testcase request

```
${#Project#ProjectLevel}
${#TestCase#TCaseProp}
${#TestSuite#TCaseProp}

<convertCurrency>${#TestSuite#TCaseProp}</ssp:SystemUsername>
```

System will automatically replace the property value in above request

https://www.soapui.org/scripting-properties/tips-tricks.html <-- Helpful link which can explain in detail about property transfer

Answer (score 0):

Well the following Script works. 
Just to change as

```
Steps.each { s ->
   id.each { i ->
     s.getAt(0).setPropertyValue("apiId", i.toString())            
  }
}
```

Here `id` is a `ArrayList` type. So We can loop through the `List`.

PS: We can do the same using `for` loop.